# Customized documentation comments in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I know there is an integrated documentation comment generator using key `option`+`command`+`/` in Xcode instead of VVDocumenter from Xcode 8. And it will automatically generate comment of a method like the following:

```
/**
Some Description
@param someParam   description of param
@return            description of return
*/
```

Then I want to add some customized tags to it like author and date, and make it automatically generate these tags every time, like the following:

```
/**
Some Description
@Author            me
@Date              05/01/2018
@param someParam   description of param
@return            description of return
*/
```

So how can I change the documentation comment template?